# Does Mapkit uses Google Maps API V3?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I am using iPhone SDK 3.2.2 and 4.1 to develop application that uses Mapkit.

Does Mapkit uses Google Maps API V3 and hence I do not require a key for that OR does it uses V2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a Google Maps API key at all to use MapKit. The Google Maps APIs v2 and v3 are JavaScript APIs. MapKit does not use JavaScript so the question whether it uses the v2 or v3 API makes no sense. Apple probably has a special agreement with Google and accesses the map tiles directly, no Javascript intervention required.